# Search higher in array

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter

I have price combinations which are arrays of objects. And I have traveler ages which are an array of numbers. So price combinations have fields like min age and max age and I want to filter travelers ages higher or lower than min age or max age. am stuck on this really don't know how to do it.

```
  const travelerAges = [5, 10, 35, 50]

  priceCombinations.filter((priceCombination) => {
    if (priceCombination.minAge > travelerAges && priceCombination.maxAge > travelerAges) {
      return false
    } else if (priceCombination.maxAge < travelerAges) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  })
```

Getting error on IF.

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'number[]'

Any ideas on how can I do this operation?

Comment: *I want to filter travelers ages higher or lower than min age or max age.* could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1):

I do not get the mentioned error while trying to execute your provided code. Yet one issue is that `travelerAges` is an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). You need to extract its lowest and highest value first.

```
Math.min(...travelerAges) //REM: Lowest value
Math.max(...travelerAges) //REM: Highest value
```

See [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

```js
//"traveler ages which are an array of numbers."
const travelerAges = [5, 10, 35, 50];

//"price combinations which are arrays of objects. price combinations have fields like min age and max age."
const priceCombinations = [];

//REM: Generating random data
for(let i=0; i<99; i++){
    const
        tMax = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50),
        tMin = tMax - Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);

    priceCombinations.push({minAge: tMin, maxAge: tMax})
};

//"I want to filter travelers ages higher or lower than min age or max age."
//REM: Assuming that means to return all priceCombination with a minAge >= min and a maxAge <= max.
const filterPrices = (array, min, max) => {
    return array.filter((priceCombination) => {
        return (
            //REM: price has to be above or equal passed min
            priceCombination.minAge >= min &&
            //REM: price has to be below or equal passed max
            priceCombination.maxAge <= max
        )
    })
};

//REM: Calling the filter
console.log(
  'Min: ' + Math.min(...travelerAges),
  'Max: ' + Math.max(...travelerAges),
  
  filterPrices(
    priceCombinations,
    Math.min(...travelerAges),
    Math.max(...travelerAges)
  )
);
```

Comment: I found antoher solution, but thanks for response.

Comment: @Boychik You should post your solution here and accept it. So that future visitors can profit from it.

Answer (score 0):

choose array index first

for example:

```
travAgeMin = Math.min.apply(null, travelerAges)
travAgeMax = Math.max.apply(null, travelerAges)

priceCombinations.filter((priceCombination) => {
  if (priceCombination.minAge > travAgeMin && priceCombination.maxAge > travAgeMin) {
    return false
  } else if (priceCombination.maxAge < travAgeMax) {
    return false
  }
  return true
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. with Math. min and max I will get only 5 and 50 ages. But what about the middle ages? 10, 35,